# How can I detect that there are parts of the code that do not match the ios version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

There are various features that I use in the project. For example, the stock pictures that come after iOS 12. For example, OTP feature after iOS 12

The application version is set to ios 11. But I want it to warn in the code. I can't see it

Can I get a message like "You have to open an if block to use this feature"?

Answer (score 2):

Xcode does provide these types of warnings?!

You should get something like '*feature* is only available in iOS 12.0 or newer' when using something that is not available in the target iOS version. Those you need to guard with the usual

```
if ( @available( iOS 12, * ) )
```

and the warning will go away.

**Based on comment**

I assume based on the question you have your version set to 11 but based on your comment you need to set this correctly, e.g. in Xcode next to the target it should look something like this (for an iOS 10).

[image: Target iOS version]

If you use that you without the guard you should get a warning similar to this one

[image: Xcode availability warning]

The `-Wunguarded-availability` and `-Wunguarded-availability-new` compiler flags should be on (the default) but you can force this in the project's build settings under *Other warning flags*.

**Update**

I used Xcode 12.1 for this. Created a new default iOS project. Then in the target, select iOS 11 as shown below.

[image: Target iOS project]

Then to the view controller created by the project I added a text field, linked it as a property as shown below and immediately the warning that you are looking for popped up.

[image: warning]

**Thanks Ol Sen Xcode setting**

Based on Ol Sen's comment - yes, check that this is enabled. Should be by default. Note you can set it under the target, but as in the image, it is better to set this at the *project* level.

[image: Xcode more settings]

Comment: So i need to follow which ios version use this ? I need to find myself ?

Comment: I thought you said you set the target to iOS 11? I updated the answer ... what version of Xcode are you using

Comment: My development target is iOS 11. I added a new feature that includes One Time Password but it need to be ios 12 and upper. In addition i wrote code 1 line but i did'nt block this with if block ( version control ) . When i test the app it crashed. Xcode did'nt show me ( like "you're using this but your development target is ios 11 you need to use if block" )

Comment: _txtLoginPhoneCode.contentMode = UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode;

Comment: I copied and pasted that in as can be seen in the update.

Comment: `Warn if an API that is newer than the deployment target is used without "if (@available(...))" guards. = CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY` or @skaak mentioned flags.

Comment: @OlSen thanks I've updated my visual novel based on your comment.

Comment: I solved that problem. My problem was xcode . Thanks for all